# what is the use of getchar() in following program

Tags: c, string, ubuntu, pointers, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUM_DAYS_IN_WEEK 7


typedef struct
{
    char *acDayName;   
    int iDate;        
    char *acActivity;   
}DAYTYPE;

void fnFreeCal(DAYTYPE *); 
void fnDispCal(DAYTYPE *);
void fnReadCal(DAYTYPE *); 
DAYTYPE *fnCreateCal();

int main() 
{
    // Create the calendar
    DAYTYPE *weeklyCalendar = fnCreateCal();

    // Read data from the keyboard
    fnReadCal(weeklyCalendar);

    // Display the week's activity details
    fnDispCal(weeklyCalendar);

    // Free allocated memory
    fnFreeCal(weeklyCalendar);

    return 0;
}

DAYTYPE *fnCreateCal() 
{
    DAYTYPE *calendar = (DAYTYPE *)malloc(NUM_DAYS_IN_WEEK * sizeof(DAYTYPE));

    
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_DAYS_IN_WEEK; i++) 
    {
        calendar[i].acDayName = NULL;
        calendar[i].iDate = 0;
        calendar[i].acActivity = NULL;
    }

    return calendar;
}

void fnReadCal(DAYTYPE *calendar) 
{
    char cChoice;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_DAYS_IN_WEEK; i++) 
    {
        printf("Do you want to enter details for day %d [Y/N]: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%c", &cChoice); 
        getchar();
        
        if(tolower(cChoice) == 'n')
            continue;
        
        printf("Day Name: ");
        char nameBuffer[50];
        scanf("%s", nameBuffer);
        calendar[i].acDayName = strdup(nameBuffer);  


        printf("Date: ");
        scanf("%d", &calendar[i].iDate);

        
        printf("Activity: ");
        char activityBuffer[100];
        scanf(" %[^\n]", activityBuffer); 
        calendar[i].acActivity = strdup(activityBuffer); 

        printf("\n");
        getchar();      
    }
}


void fnDispCal(DAYTYPE *calendar) 
{
    printf("\nWeek's Activity Details:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_DAYS_IN_WEEK; i++) 
    {
        printf("Day %d:\n", i + 1);
        if(calendar[i].iDate == 0)
        {
            printf("No Activity\n\n");
            continue;
        }
        
        printf("  Day Name: %s\n", calendar[i].acDayName);
        printf("  Date: %d\n", calendar[i].iDate);
        printf("  Activity: %s\n\n", calendar[i].acActivity);
    }
}

void fnFreeCal(DAYTYPE *calendar) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_DAYS_IN_WEEK; i++) 
    {
        free(calendar[i].acDayName);
        free(calendar[i].acActivity);
    }
    free(calendar);
}
```

This is a program to Declare a calendar as an array of 7 elements (A dynamically Created array) to represent 7 days of a week. Each Element of the array is a structure having three fields. The first
field is the name of the Day (A dynamically allocated String), The second field is the
date of the Day (A integer), the third field is the description of the activity for a
particular day (A dynamically allocated String). Write functions create(), read() and display(); to create the calendar, to read the data from the keyboard and to print weeks activity details report on screen.
There are two getchar() methods in this program, why is getchar() necessary.

Comment: Ask the author of the code why he inserted the calls of getchar. It would be enough to write scanf(" %c", &cChoice); instead of scanf("%c", &cChoice); Pay attention to the leading space in the format string.

Comment: It is a bad kludge sometimes seen after `scanf(" %[^\n]", activityBuffer);`. Remove it. Nobody does that after the other format specifiers, which also leave the newline char in the buffer. But the space in `" %[^\n]"` is correct.

Comment: @Swathi A Answering your question I can say that there are used calls of getchar due to the low qualification of the programmer who wrote the code.

Comment: If you use `scanf(" %c", &cChoice);` then it will skip leading whitespace just like the space before `%` in `" %[^\n]"` does. Then you probably wouldn't need to try consuming them.

Comment: As the duplicate question notes, the `scanf()` functions leave the newline in the input buffer after an input.  Using `getchar()` is a fragile attempt to remove the newline.  When successful, it means that a subsequent line-input operation (`fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`, for example) doesn't stop immediately because of the newline.  It's fragile because if the user types a space at the end of the input, the `getchar()` reads the space instead of the newline.  It should be a loop like: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) continue;`, which could be a static inline function.

Answer (score 0):

It's being used to consume the trailing newline from the previous input.

Unlike the `%s` and `%d` conversion specifiers, the `%c` and `%[` conversion specifiers don't skip over leading whitespace, so they can erroneously pick up a newline from the previous input.  Without the `getchar` call, the second time through the loop the `scanf("%c", &cChoice);` call will read the newline from the previous activity input and assign it to `cChoice`, throwing off your remaining inputs.

There is a better way to deal with this, though.  You can use a leading blank in the format string:

```
scanf( " %c", &cChoice );
```

That leading blank will consume any leading whitespace, so you don't need a separate `getchar` call before it.

Comment: You have not answered the second question: " Also explain the program"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That's why they should only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Barmar That is why the question should be closed at once.:)